# C program that returns current answer and previous answer

Tags: c, linux, parameters

I've got this code that converts the numbers received as parameters form decimal to binary. Each parameter should appear on a new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments.");
        return 0;
    }
    
    int counter=0;
    int decimal, binar[100], rest, i = 0;
    
    while(counter<argc)
    {
    decimal = atoi(argv[counter]);
    rest = decimal;
    counter++;
    while (rest != 0)
    {
        binar[i] = rest % 2;
        rest = rest / 2;
        i++;
    
    }
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        printf("%d", binar[j]);
    printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem when running the program such as:

```
 ./biti 1 2 3 4

1
101
11101
10011101
```

It returns the current number followed by the previous answers, how can i fix this?

Comment: Fix what? Please [edit] and show also the _expected output_.

Comment: Reset `i` back to `0` at  the top of the outer `while` loop.

Comment: Put `i = 0;` just before `while (rest != 0)`.

Comment: note that you also need to check for 0 input or you won't print anything

Comment: Aside: Rather then `while (rest != 0) { ... }`, use `do { .... } while (rest != 0);` to handle `decimal == 0`.  A special check for 0 is not then needed.